# VLC - Hide bottom time bar and top right time, when skipping forward or backward

Tags: vlc-media-player

I watch recorded NBA games on VLC.

An important thing for me is to not know how much time there is left in the recording, so that I have no idea how or when the game will end. (This matters especially near the end of games. If it's near the end of the 4th quarter but I see that there is still 30 minutes of recording, I can easily infer that there'll be at least one overtime.)

Full screen mostly accomplishes this. However...

When I hit small skip, large skip etc. (to skip over commercials and stuff),  a (faint) outline of the time bar appears at the bottom, and the time elapsed / total time appears at the top right.

So my question is: How do I hide these?

Screenshot below, with what I'm talking about circled in red.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question - found this solution:
https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/windows-7/vlc-media-player-how-to-disable-the-pause-and-play-on-screen-icons/

Although it refers to "subtitles", following the steps does in fact effect what you're trying to do.

Pasting the text below in case that page is unavailable in the future:

=========================================================================

By default when you pause and play a video in VLC Media Player icons appear at the top right of the screen that show what the video is doing. These icons are part of the on screen display functionality, also known as OSD.

VLC-DisplayOSD1

The steps below show how to display OSD.

With VLC Media Player open, click on the ‘Tools’ menu then ‘Preferences’
VLC-DisplayOSD2
Under ‘Show settings’ (bottom left of the window) click on ‘All’
Scroll to the bottom of the list on the left and click on ‘Subtitles / OSD’
Un-tick ‘On Screen Display’
Click ‘Save’ to save the changes.
VLC-DisplayOSD3

Comment: Confirmed that this worked. To do this on VLC 3.016 running in macOS 11.5.2 used these steps: Preferences > Show All > Video > Subtitles/OCD > On Screen Display (uncheck)